# Magento whitescreening when data model load called

Tags: php, magento

I've set up my config.xml and my controller, my data model class and resource class and I can see that the classes are loading and can echo out the object and NULL data object information.

However, when I try to call the ->load method of the data model object, I get the whitescreen of death.  I've double checked and triple checked my config.xml and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or what to look for next...can anyone help?

Thanks!

Kristina

Comment: What did you do to resolve this?

Comment: It turned out that I had put some code that belonged in the EAV resource model function in the data model declaration function...which caused an error on load().   Once I went back through Alan's tutorials I realized what I had done wrong.  Thanks btw, Alan, for your response and for your excellent tutorials!  I'm a longtime PHP hacker but totally new to Magento...this is my first project using Magento and I'm building a custom subscription-editing module for a client.

Answer (score 2):

PHP never errors out without telling you why, it's just a matter of finding the right log.

First, check your Magento exception log

```
var/log/exception.log
```

Second, check your PHP Error log.  If you're not sure where the that, run `phpinfo()` from a blank file on your server and look for the

```
error_log
```

variable.  If this isn't set, set it via the `ini_set` function, or by changing your `php.ini` file.

If you leave `error_log` unset, PHP will send logs to the "SAPI error logger", which is a fancy way of saying your apache error log.

Finally, although it won't help with all white screen cases, try turning developer mode on.  There's the following line in index.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

So either set `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` in your `.htaccess` file, or just comment out the conditional.  This will turn off the default error reporting and output exceptions/errors/warnings/etc to the browser.